# Crm 2013 + To remove comma from Whole Number field

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a field on my form of type "Whole Number". I want to remove comma from the field and display simple number. I know there exists a System Setting to remove comma however it will apply to all the fields i want to do it one only my current field.
Any Supported or UnSupported code will help. I tried some unsupported code too .
However this didn't work for me.

```
var number = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_numberfield").getValue();
if(number !=null)
   document.getElementById('new_numberfield').value = number;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible supported solution would be to:

- Create a new text field on the form
- Hide the whole number field

then in JavaScript

- On form load get the value from the whole number field
- Update the text field with the whole number field value

To persist changes to the new text field

- Trigger a JavaScript function on-change of the text field
- The function parses the string to a number
- The function then updates the whole number field

**Edit**

This is an example for the number of employees field on the account entity.

**Create a new text field for the account entity**

[image]

**On the form add both the old decimal field (hidden) and the new text field (visible)**
During development I will leave both fields visible.
[image]

Add this on-change function to new_wrapper_numberofemployees:

```javascript
function UpdateBackingDecimalField (){
    var stringValue = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_wrapper_numberofemployees").GetValue();
    var numberValue = parseInt(stringValue);
    if(isNaN(numberValue)) {
        // new_wrapper_numberofemployees did not contain a number
        // show error message for bad user input
    }
    else { // update the real numberofemployees field
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("numberofemployees").setValue(numberValue);
    }
}
```

Add this form-on-load function:

```
function UpdateVisibleField() {
    var decimalValue = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("numberofemployees").getValue();
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_wrapper_numberofemployees").setValue(decimalValue);
}
```

The JavaScript has not been tested and will certainly need more work; it is just to get the idea across.

Comment: Hey,Thanks for the reply.
I dont want to recreate the field (as per the requirement). Also the field is editable. Even if there is any unsupported way please suggest.

Comment: I am not suggesting that you re-create the field, just hide the field and create a wrapper field for it. The user will interact with the new wrapper field instead of the whole number field. The idea is to create a binding between a new text field and the existing whole number field.

Comment: I agree to what u say but this field is reffered in several reports, in that case i will have to change its reference everywhere because even if i update this it will not remove the comma,u see.
Can u help me with the above unsupported code.i changed the field name to 'new_numberfield_i' ,'new_numberfield_d' , 'new_numberfield_c' but it does not seem to work

Comment: The report can still reference the old field. There is no need to change the reports. I will add some JavaScript to the answer to clarify.

Comment: Yes can u please provide some code like how the value will be set in textfield and how again it will be reset in wholenumber field.